# Saving User Data (Swift)

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making an app, and it needs to allow the user to save their data, as if they get a high score, or if they unlock a special character and that character will be used when their app starts up. And if they want to go back to a different character, that would save. Where should I go to find good resources for this?

Comment: This question is too broad to get a useful answer here. There are four primary ways iOS apps save data: `NSUserDefaults`, `NSCoding`, Core Data, or saving data to a remote API (typically a web service over HTTP). You should compare them to select the best approach for your app, and ask a more specific question with example code if you have difficulty implementing it.

Comment: The question is very broad I suggest trying to implement Core Data and asking for more specific help with the code if needed.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well, there are quite a few ways to persist data in iOS.  Archiving, UserDefaults, Plists, and of course Core Data(list not exhaustive); each can do a piece or all of what you need(in the case of Core Data).  If you want certain items to remain in the cloud, you can look at Cloud Kit or third party solutions like Parse, or you can roll your own server.

The Apple documentation is a good resource, also there are many books on Core Data.  If I were you, I would look into Core Data.

Good Luck!